# Save dataURL as image with Filepicker.io exportWidget

Tags: filepicker.io, todataurl

It seems like using the Filepicker.io javascript API you can save a dataURL, but I'm wondering if it's possible to save a dataURL mime-typed as "image/png" with the Filepicker.io export widget? When I attempt this I get an exception: Invalid file to export. I read that using the JS API you need to strip the "data:image/png;base64," prefix, however that seems to give the same exception.

I'm stripping this off like so:

```
myCanvasImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png').split(',',2)[1];
```

But this seems to throw the same error. Any idea if this is possible with the Filepicker widget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it inside filepicker store function. It will deal with base64 decoding.

```
var dataURL = $('#canvasElement')[0].toDataURL().split(',', 2)[1];

filepicker.store(
  dataURL,
  {
    base64decode: true,
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg'
  },
  function(InkBlob){
    filepicker.exportFile(
      InkBlob,
      {suggestedFilename:"yourFileName"},
      function(InkBlob){
        console.log(InkBlob);
      },
      function(FPError) {
        console.log(FPError.toString());
      }
    );
  }, 
  function(FPError) {
    console.log(FPError.toString());
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a different way than I thought it could be done. This seems to be a good way to go. Thanks again!